# Center svg with Ariutta svg-pan-zoom library

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using ariutta/svg-pan-zoom plugin to manage pan/zoom of a SVG element. I would like to center the svg draw in the wrapping div when I click to "zoom reset".

```
<div id="wrapDiv" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;">
  <svg width="1000" height="500px">
   <g class="viewport">
       ....
   </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no listener hook for *zoom reset* button. However there is a listener for *zoom* and *pan* events. You can cache svgpanzoom sizes (such as zoom and pan) after it started (using `getSizes`). Then on each zoom or pan compare new values with initial values.

In order to center you can use `center` method.

```
// Get instance
var panZoomTiger = svgPanZoom('#demo-tiger');

// Center
panZoomTiger.center();
```